# Problem converting different versions of pine script to each other

Tags: pine-script

I started learning pain script language about a month ago

This code is for version two of the pine script

I could not find the document for version two

That is, I could not find any document to refer to and know the syntax of version two

How do I convert this to version 4?

```
//Author - Chandan Kumar
//Thanks to Rajandran of www.marketcalls.in for original supertrend script
//Multi time frame supertrend - 6 timeframe supertrends in one chart
study("Multitimeframe Supertrend", overlay = true)

Factor=input(4, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(10, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

Trend15 = security(tickerid,"15",Trend)
Trend30 = security(tickerid,"30",Trend)
Trend60 = security(tickerid,"60",Trend)
Trend120 = security(tickerid,"120",Trend)
Trend240 = security(tickerid,"240",Trend)
TrendD = security(tickerid,"D",Trend)
TrendW = security(tickerid,"W",Trend)

Tsl15 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl)
Tsl30 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl)
Tsl60 = security(tickerid,"60",Tsl)
Tsl120 = security(tickerid,"120",Tsl)
Tsl240 = security(tickerid,"240",Tsl)
TslD = security(tickerid,"D",Tsl)
TslW = security(tickerid,"W",Tsl)

//linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red
linecolor15 = Trend15 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor30 = Trend30 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor60 = Trend60 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor120 = Trend120 == 1 ? green : red
linecolor240 = Trend240 == 1 ? green : red
linecolorD = TrendD == 1 ? green : red
linecolorW = TrendW == 1 ? green : red

plot(Tsl15, color = linecolor15 , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend15")
plot(Tsl30, color = linecolor30 , style = linebr , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend30")
plot(Tsl60, color = linecolor60 , style = circles, linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend60")
plot(Tsl120, color = linecolor120 , style = cross,linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend120")
plot(Tsl240, color = linecolor240 , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend240")
plot(TslD, color = linecolorD , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendD")
plot(TslW, color = linecolorW , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendW")
//plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
//plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

//plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
//plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

I did 90% of the work with research, but there is still an error

**Bottom line error**

**error :
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 25: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function.**

How do I continue? And are the changes I made correct?

```
//Author - Chandan Kumar
//Thanks to Rajandran of www.marketcalls.in for original supertrend script
//Multi time frame supertrend - 6 timeframe supertrends in one chart
//@version=4
study("Multitimeframe Supertrend", overlay = true)

Factor=input(4, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(10, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

float TrendUp=na
float TrendDown=na
TrendUp:=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown:=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend() => 
    float Trend=na
    Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl() => 
    Tsl = Trend()==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

tickerid = syminfo.ticker
Trend15 = security(tickerid,"15",Trend())
Trend30 = security(tickerid,"30",Trend())
Trend60 = security(tickerid,"60",Trend())
Trend120 = security(tickerid,"120",Trend())
Trend240 = security(tickerid,"240",Trend())
TrendD = security(tickerid,"D",Trend())
TrendW = security(tickerid,"W",Trend())

Tsl15 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl())
Tsl30 = security(tickerid,"15",Tsl())
Tsl60 = security(tickerid,"60",Tsl())
Tsl120 = security(tickerid,"120",Tsl())
Tsl240 = security(tickerid,"240",Tsl())
TslD = security(tickerid,"D",Tsl())
TslW = security(tickerid,"W",Tsl())

//linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red
linecolor15 = Trend15 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor30 = Trend30 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor60 = Trend60 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor120 = Trend120 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolor240 = Trend240 == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolorD = TrendD == 1 ? color.green : color.red
linecolorW = TrendW == 1 ? color.green : color.red

plot(Tsl15, color = linecolor15 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend15")
plot(Tsl30, color = linecolor30 , style = plot.style_linebr , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend30")
plot(Tsl60, color = linecolor60 , style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend60")
plot(Tsl120, color = linecolor120 , style = plot.style_cross,linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend120")
plot(Tsl240, color = linecolor240 , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend240")
plot(TslD, color = linecolorD , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendD")
plot(TslW, color = linecolorW , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrendW")
//plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
//plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

//plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
//plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

Comment: You should search for previously answered questions regarding how to handle v2 to v4 self referencing variables and mutable variables in security calls.

Comment: @rumpypumpydumpy
I edited, please tell me